# Ember generated action or jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an ember application which works fine. But user's interaction does some DOM insertion like below...

```
$(.test).append(<a {{action "getData"}}>Get Data</a>);
```

The problem is that Ember seems do not recognize that an action "getData" has been added to the DOM. Nothing is  happening when I click the element. Any thoughts on this?

Another way I am trying to do is:

```
 //create the element
 $(.test).append(<a id="idnum">Get Data</a>);

 //make click listener
 $('#idnum').click(function(){
 console.log("get data");
}
```

my question is where should i place the code inside the component so the it can listen on the click event. Thanks.

Comment: If you use ember you should avoid manual DOM manipulation. Have you considered to use a handlebars `{{#if}}` to render the element you want to append?

Comment: Hi, i guess I made my example too simple, the DOM that is being inserted is actually rendered by a third party jquery library (w2ui grid) after it does gets data from an ajax call, it renders a table column with several <a id="idnum1">Get Data</a> thats why the {{#if}} is not seems an option.

Answer (score 2):

You should do it in Ember way. Try handlebars {{#if}} helper to render an element dynamically.

```
{{#if canGetData}}
<a {{action "getData"}}>Get Data</a>
{{/if}}
```

Here you can set the value of the canGetData to true in the controller based on the users action.

Answer (score 1):

Like Lux suggested avoid DOM manipulation. I prefer the following approach,
if it is dynamic then you can consider wrapping DOM element as a new component and use component helper.
find sample [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/14d3fb985b9e507d411fac5e394319dd?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

In application.js

```
    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
      linksArray:[ Ember.Object.create({value:'Text to display',routename:'home'}),
                   Ember.Object.create({value:'Text to display2',routename:'home'})],
      actions:{
        addItem(){
           this.get('linksArray').pushObject(Ember.Object.create({value:'AddedDynamically',routename:'home'}));
        }
      } 
    });
```

in Application.hbs

```
<h1>Welcome to {{appName}}</h1>
<br>
{{#each linksArray as |item|}}
 {{component 'link-to' item.value item.route }}
{{/each}}
<button {{action 'addItem'}}>Add Item</button>
<br>
{{outlet}}
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: You can put $('#idnum').click(function(){
 console.log("get data");
} code in didInsertElement hook of the component.

Answer (score 1):

The first example can't work because ember does not analythe the Handlebars elements in the DOM, but rather parses your Handlebars template with HTMLBars, which is a full HTML parser, and then renders it manually by inserting elements, not text into the DOM.

However the second example is the way to go if you have to rely on external code that does manual DOM manipulation. And it *does* work. Checkout [this](https://ember-twiddle.com/f086a702f73cc8895d918d59cae30923?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) twiddle.

This does work:

```
this.$('.target').append('<a id="idnum">Get Data</a>');

this.$('#idnum').on('click', () => {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Just make sure that the DOM is ready. So do it in the `didInsertElement` hook or after the user clicked a button or so.

Comment: Well, if a question solves your problem consider to accept the answer so its listed as accepted. Also consider to up vote instead of thank you comments. They help much more if another user finds this page.

Comment: yeah I wanted to... but I get notifications saying my vote doesn't show but it was counted... thanks again!