# create x number of components within a component in ember 2.8

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

So I have two components in my Ember app, game-instance and game-card. The idea is that I will pass a 'cards' number attribute to game-instance and it will create x instances of game-card. Here's the setup

game.hbs (the main file):

```
<div>
  {{input type="number" min="2" max="24" placeholder="enter a number from 4 to 24"
                        value=inputValue
                        key-up=handleInputChange}}

  {{game-instance cards=inputValue}}
</div>
```

game-instance.hbs

```
<div>
  <!-- iteratively create game cards based on cards attribute passed -->
</div>
```

game-card.hbs

```
<div class="gamecard">
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

When trying to figure out how to write up the game-instance.hbs logic, I've seen how handlebars allows you to iterate over an array. This is not really what I want. What I want is this behaviour:

1. game-instance reads its cards attribute passed from game.hbs. In this case let's assume 6
2. a type of for-loop logic creates six instances of game-card within game-instance.

Is there an appropriate handlebars syntax to achieve this? If not, how can I achieve similar behaviour? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is you need to use `component` helper along with `#each` block with cards array. so that whenever we change cards array,it will re-render the whole block.

After user entering input,you can create/update cardsArray. that will automatically rerender game-card component in game-instance component

**game-instance.hbs**

```
{{#each cardsArray as |value,index|}}
 {{component 'game-card' value }}
{{/each}}
```

Whenever we change cardsArray using pushObject or chagning the entire reference then then `each` block will be rendered.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying to create a new component called, say, 'game-instance-helper' and have that component take in the cards input and return an array?

Comment: In this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38472236/5771666  I created link-to dynamically..You can follow this approach for game-card component too.